# Can I simplify this CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure about this but is there a way I can simplify:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px / 10px 0px 0px 10px;
```

Comment: Don't forget, you need to specify `border-radius` as well as `-moz-border-radius` to be cross-browser compatible. And if you want to include IE, You may also need to include a hack like CSS3Pie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the horizontal and vetical radii to a single declaration:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
```

However, you cannot simplify it further, as radii are only inherited diagonally. (bottom left will take top right's value if bottom left value does not exist).

Comment: Even simper, `-moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;`

Comment: Ooo, forgot about that, @Marcel. I usually try to keep my statements as explicit as possible to avoid confusion. :) @Mariko, np! solution? :D